# How to write conditional mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table

**Books**

```
id, name, organisationId, status
```

so, now what I want to get is the books with an organisationId as 3.
which is ...

```
SELECT * FROM books where id= '3'
```

the problem is that I cant think of a way, where I could also get the books with status as public irrespective of organisationId.

I'm new to understanding mysql queries thats why I'm asking this so that I can understand.

Comment: Use AND / OR to add additional conditions to your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

use `and` with your where clause ,same way you could use `or` in place of and

```
SELECT * FROM books where id= 3 and status like '%public%'
```

Comment: I think he should use `OR` because he want's to display "status as public irrespective of organisationId."

Comment: @boka18 i added that in description

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you'll wanna do:

```
SELECT * FROM books where id= '3' OR status='public'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `OR` with your posted query.

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=3 OR status='public'
```

As you want to get all the info irrespective of id.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for all books with `organisationID=3` you need this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM books where organisationID= '3'
```

If you looking all books the either have `organisationID=3` or `status='public'` you need this clause:

```
SELECT * FROM books where organisationID= '3' OR status='public'
```

Take a look a the SQL standards and/or the MySQL manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html